# SSRS Column Groups for Year over Year Comparison

Tags: reporting-services

I'm attempting to create a year-over-year comparison but I'm having difficulty getting the columns arranged how I need them.

Current SSRS Setup

Imgur :

[image]

Desired output

```
| Metric | 2019FW16 | 2018FW16 | YoY  | 2019FW17 | 2018FW17 | YoY | 2019FW18 | 2018FW18 | YoY  | 2019FW19 | 2018FW18 | YoY  |
|--------|----------|----------|------|----------|----------|-----|----------|----------|------|----------|----------|------|
| Sales  | 150      | 140      | 7%   | 200      | 187      | 7%  | 180      | 198      | -9%  | 600      | 700      | -14% |
| Orders | 60       | 90       | -33% | 160      | 100      | 60% | 120      | 300      | -60% | 560      | 600      | -7%  |
```

For the each of the time_frames I added a column visibility expression.

```
=IIF(Fields!time_frame.Value = 2019, True, False) for 2019
=IIF(Fields!time_frame.Value = 2018, True, False) for 2018
```

The trouble I'm encourntering is how to get a YoY column between each of the time frame groupings.  If I enter a column visibility expression into the YoY column the report does have the columns correctly placed for the report but it does not calculate the YoY change correctly due to the year expression.  Without an expression the report just adds a column after each time frame like below.

```
| Metric | 2019FW16 | YoY | 2018FW16 | YoY | 2019FW17 | YoY | 2018FW17 | YoY | 2019FW18 | YoY | 2018FW18 | YoY |
|--------|----------|-----|----------|-----|----------|-----|----------|-----|----------|-----|----------|-----|
```

I wanted to enter a column so I can enter an expression

```
(ReportItems!Sales2019.Value - ReportItems!Sales2018.Value)/(ReportItems!Sales2018.Value)
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish the desired output?

Comment: Could you explain how you are grouping on the column groups?  You may have to do some hacky thing where you separate the `FW16`, `FW17`, etc and group the three based on that...

Comment: @Steve-o169 The columns are grouped on a "business name" then time_frame.  There are 3 business names with 8 FWs, so a total of 24 rows from my query that are pulled into this query.